# Making input() ignore capitalization or lowercase and etc

Tags: python, input

so recently i was making survey maker and i did this:

```
print('ABC or DEF?')
test0 = input()
if test0 == 'ABC':
   print('You choose ABC')

elif test0 == 'DEF':
   print('You choose DEF')
```

now if i put input "ABC" or "DEF" it print "You choose ABC" or "DEF"

but if i put input "abc" or "def" it wouldn't print.. i know i can use the "OR" gate but.. what if it was "AbC" or "dEF"??

i just want the python itself ignore the input uppercase or lowercase so i don't tired of making the "OR" gate for every blah blah blah...

please help me

i tried "OR" gate but like i said.. i am tired for every case i need to yeah blah blah blah

Comment: String objects have the method `upper`. Just compare the converted input string with "ABC".

Comment: when you want to ignore case, declare a new variable and convert the input into capital letters, say `caps = test0.upper()`. Then, you can make a conditional statement like, `if caps == 'ABC':` or `if caps == 'DEF:'`

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you, but can you help me how to do it?

Comment: It was already shown by @SuramuthuR

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your input string to be upper case when you are taking the input :

```
print('ABC or DEF?')
test0 = input().upper() # here you make your input string uppercase
if test0 == 'ABC':
   print('You choose ABC')

elif test0 == 'DEF':
   print('You choose DEF')
```